# What's the difference between 'chsh -s' and 'export SHELL'?

Tags: unix, terminal, shell

I think that the `export` command is only active per login session, but I'm not sure. `chsh` I think is more permanent. Can someone clear this up for me (preferably with links/docs)? Thanks.

Comment: `chsh` changes your login shell permanently (usually in /etc/passwd). See http://linux.die.net/man/1/chsh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`chsh`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chsh.1.html) is generally what you want to use if you want to change your customary shell. It updates `/etc/passwd` so that your newly-selected shell is started upon each future login.

`export SHELL` doesn't do anything on its own. The [`SHELL`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html) variable is sometimes used by programs that want to spawn an external shell (say, to give you a command line in a certain directory, or with certain environment variables pre-set). If you want to run another shell temporarily, you would typically just run it directly like any other program. For example, if your normal shell is `/bin/bash` but you want to test something under `/bin/tcsh`, then just issue `/bin/tcsh` on the bash command line.

Comment: The `SHELL` link was the wrong link, BTW; fixed.